# Why reference point to different values?

Tags: c#

Can someone explain why this code outputs 5? I thought that packaging is happening here, the value is wrapped in an object and sent to the heap. And the reference stays on the stack.
And then x and y will point to the same address on the heap. But it is not.

```
object x = 5;
object y = x;
x = 10;
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: x is a variable. You assign a value to that variable. In the case of `x = 10`, the value is the reference to the boxed integer 10. You replace the value of a variable. You do not modify any object instance. It's basically the same as doing `s1 = "Foo"; s2 = s1; s1 = "Bar"`, with s2 then at end still referring to the "Foo" string...

Comment: Nothing in the code ever *modifies* an object referenced by a variable.  All this does is re-assign the variable to a new value.  This has nothing to do with boxing.  Re-assigning a variable does nothing to whatever object that variable used to reference.  You'd see the same behavior with any types, any values.

Comment: Thank you, can you describe how it looks like in terms of memory allocation on the stack and on the heap?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is the same as

```cs
int x = 5;
int y = x; // copy value from x to y: y = 5
x = 10; // set x to 10, y is unchanged: y = 5
Console.WriteLine(y)
// outputs: 5
```

This is the same as with reference types.

```cs
class A
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public A(int i) { Data = i; }
    public override string ToString() { return Data.ToString(); }
}

object x = new A(5);
object y = x; // y is reference to x' object
> x = new A(10); // x is now pointing to a new object, y is unchanged
Console.WriteLine(y)
// outputs: 5
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this happen for all value types?

Comment: Yes, that's the example with `int`

Comment: in addition to @BurnsBA check object immutability